# Do information separators constitute line-breaks in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, newline, whitespace, line-breaks, paragraph

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) article which lists all Unicode whitespaces mentions 7 of them as line/paragraph separating characters (LF, VT, FF, CR, NEL, LS, PS). Here there is nothing given about ASCII 'information separator' characters (FS, GS, RS, US). But surprisingly FS, GS, RS have '[paragraph separator](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/bidiclass/B) (B)' as their bidirectional class. This is confusing.

Now, when I encounter one of these 'information separator' characters in a text, should I consider them as line-break or not? In other words, if I am writing a function which splits at line breaks, then should I split at these three characters? (`string.splitlines()` function in Python does consider them as line breaks. I don't know about other implementations.)

For example:

1. Both in the linked Wikipedia table and in the Unicode bidi class database, LF is considered as line-break. So I can break line when I encounter that character.
2. Both in the linked Wikipedia table and in the Unicode bidi class database, SP is not considered as line-break. So I can't break a line when I encounter that character. (suppose no word-wrap).
3. The linked Wikipedia table does not mention GS as a line-break. But the Unicode bidi class database does mention it as line-break. I'm confused: what should I do in this case? What does bidi class refer to in this case?

Here I'm only asking about the Unicode standard. But if you know, you can also mention about line-breaks in the ASCII standard.

PS: I'm not sure whether the table in the linked Wikipedia page is correct. But I wasn't able to find any other good resource which lists all whitespaces.

Comment: For starters, you can ignore the Unicode bidi class. That is used by the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/), which is not what you are doing. BiDi paragraph separators determine when the directionality resets. It does not mean that an actual paragraph is starting.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks. That almost answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FS, GS, RS, and US belong to the line break class `Combining_Mark` (`CM`). The relevant file in the Unicode Character Database for this information is [LineBreak.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/LineBreak.txt).

[UAX #14 (Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm)](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-47.html#DescriptionOfProperties) describes class `CM` as follows:

> Combining character sequences are treated as units for the purpose of
> line breaking. The line breaking behavior of the sequence is that of
> the base character.

In other words: Class `CM` characters prohibit line breaks *before* them – they essentially “glue” themselves to the previous character. However, for all other purposes, the line breaking algorithm *completely ignores* the presence of class `CM` characters. Whether or not a line break opportunity exists after a class `CM` character depends solely* on the line break class of the base character it has been applied to, i.e. the first character going backwards that is not of class `CM`.

*There are some exceptions to this rule involving mandatory breaks and a few special formatting characters, but they shouldn’t be relevant for your purposes.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what is the use of CM. Without CM also, line-break opportunity depends on the base character. Maybe can you explain with an example please.

Comment: Combining marks are characters that usually aren’t used on their own, but instead form a unit with another character. For example, you can put an acute accent on top of the letter x by writing the character U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT directly after it like so: x́. Because combining marks don’t really mean anything in isolation, only when applied to some base character, the line break class that is assigned to them causes the behaviour I described above: The line break algorithm ignores combining marks and only considers their non-combining base characters to determine where to break.

Comment: For example, the sequence x́ that I’ve shown is treated by the line break algorithm exactly as if the acute accent didn’t exist, i.e. as if there was only the letter x without any extras. The letter x (like all Unicode characters) also belongs to a certain line break class of its own, which the line break algorithm utilises to determine where to put line break opportunities inside the string. Despite the name, the class Combining_Mark also includes characters that aren’t combining marks, such as most control characters since they’re invisible anyway and don’t really matter for line breaking.

Comment: But still, why their bidi class is `paragraph separator (B)` instead of `non-spacing mark (NSM)` like U+0301?

Comment: Because that’s the class they’ve been assigned. Their bidi class being called Paragraph_Separator has *nothing* to do whatsoever with line breaks. The bidirectional algorithm and the line break algorithm operate completely separately from one another. The bidi algorithm is applied to each “paragraph” of the text individually; the contents of one “paragraph” must not affect the ordering of any other “paragraph”. Bidi class Paragraph_Separator simply describes those characters that the algorithm considers to be the boundary between two such “paragraphs”.

Comment: A “paragraph” for bidi purposes is simply any run of text that the bidi algorithm considers an independent unit. This could be literal paragraphs, separated either by line break control characters like U+000A LINE FEED or some higher protocol like the HTML <p> tag, but it also means things like different cells of a table, even if visually they’re on the same row. If used for their originally intended purpose, FS, GS, and RS would similarly indicate that the characters on either side of them belong to different such “paragraphs” in the bidi sense even without literally starting a new paragraph.